# Validar registro que possui virgula no campo em Oracle PL SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql, stored-procedures

Estou criando uma `procedure` em `PL SQL` e tenho um campo "não normalizado" que pode possuir mais de um registro separados por virgulas.

Essa  `procedure`realiza o cancelamento de envio de extratos de uma matriz (comércio) para uma conciliadora.

A matriz pode enviar para até 3 conciliadoras.

Se o cancelamento for efetuado e a matriz possuía só 1 conciliadora, essa matriz vira um EC, mantendo apenas o EC no campo CONCIL, e se possuir mais de 1, remove a conciliadora desejada e mantém as outras.
Lembrando, as conciliadoras são separadas por virgulas.

Tem algum jeito de validar esse campo e remover a conciliadora de acordo com a regra de negocio acima?

Segue o que estou desenvolvendo:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_CANCELAMENTO (
    P_COD_MATRIZ INT,
    P_CONCIL VARCHAR2, -- Parâmetro referente a coluna conciliadora
    P_ID_CONCIL INT
)
IS
BEGIN

        IF P_ID_CONCIL IS NOT NULL
        THEN
        DELETE FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_MBX WHERE ID_MBX = P_ID_CONCIL AND ID_PERFIL = (SELECT ID FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ);
        END IF;

            IF TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL.CD = 1
            THEN
            DELETE FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_CD WHERE ID_CD = P_ID_CONCIL AND ID_PERFIL = (SELECT ID FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ);
            UPDATE TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL SET CD = 0 WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ;
            ELSE IF TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_SFTP = 1
            THEN
            DELETE FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL_SFTP WHERE ID_SFTP = P_ID_CONCIL AND ID_PERFIL = (SELECT ID FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ);
            UPDATE TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL SET SFTP = 0 WHERE COD_MATRIZ = P_COD_MATRIZ;

END IF;
END IF;        
END;
/
```

Comment: Veja se a função INSTR pode funcionar para você. Minha sugestão é fazer um IF (algo dessa forma): cContem := SELECT INSTR(conteudo_metriz, conteudo_quer_apagar) as posicao FROM DUAL; IF cContem IS NOT NULL then 'AQUI SEU DELETE/UPDATE' ENDIF

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819375/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array-in-pl-sql  ideia básica string para array , trata array , array para string

Comment: Consegui trazer o a posição onde eu quero validar com a função regexp_instr porém retorna como número.
`SELECT regexp_instr('CONCILIADORAX,CONCILIADORAY', ',', 1, 1, 0, 'i') FROM dual; `
 @Motta, tem ideia de como seria array para string? dei uma olhada no link que me passou mas não consegui...